# android studio : minSdkVersion 22 error

Tags: android-studio

I am a complete beginner in android studio and I was having trouble with setting minSdkVersion to 22 for android wear. The problem is caused because of library dependency since it requires the minSdkVersion to be 23 minimum. I looked up in the web and didn't seem to find a solution of how to set the minSdkVersion to 22.
The cod is given below

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "enterprise.supti.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.support:wearable:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:percent:28.0.0-rc01'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0-rc01'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0-rc01'
    implementation 'com.android.support:wear:28.0.0-rc01'
    compileOnly 'com.google.android.wearable:wearable:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0-rc01'
}
```

Comment: how are you trying to set the version?

Comment: By changing the number of minSdkVersion.

Comment: include the code so people can help you